# SQL Server 2000 not installing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a problem.. I'm trying to install SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Edition on to Windows XP Professional in Cloud hosting, and the installation stops in stage "Starting the server and set your configuration" (probably this, but I not remembered), I waited ca 10 minutes and installation stopped and gave me the log... In the log is the czech words, I'm the translate it!

```
21:54:09 Begin Setup
21:54:09 8.00.194
21:54:09 Mode = Normal
21:54:09 ModeType = NORMAL
21:54:09 GetDefinitionEx returned: 0, Extended: 0x0
21:54:09 ValueFTS returned: 1
21:54:09 ValuePID returned: 0
21:54:09 ValueLic returned: 0
21:54:09 System: Windows NT WorkStation
21:54:09 SQL Server ProductType: Enterprise Evaluation Edition [0x3]
21:54:09 Begin Action: SetupInitialize 
21:54:09 End Action SetupInitialize
21:54:09 Begin Action:  SetupInstall
21:54:09 Reading Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CommonFilesDir ...
21:54:09 CommonFilesDir=C:\Program Files\Common Files
21:54:09 Windows Directory=C:\WINDOWS\
21:54:09 Program Files=C:\Program Files\
21:54:09 TEMPDIR=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\
21:54:09 Begin Action:  SetupInstall
21:54:09 Begin Action:  CheckFixedRequirements
21:54:09 Platform ID: 0xf000000
21:54:09 Version: 5.1.2600
21:54:09 File Version - C:\WINDOWS\system32\shdocvw.dll: 6.0.2900.5512
21:54:09 End Action:  CheckFixedRequirements
21:54:09 Begin Action:  ShowDialogs
21:54:09 Initial Dialog Mask: 0x8300037, Disable Back=0x1
21:54:09 Begin Action ShowDialogsHlpr: 0x1
21:54:09 Begin Action:  DialogShowSdWelcome
21:54:10 End Action  DialogShowSdWelcome
21:54:10 Dialog 0x1 returned: 1
21:54:10 End Action ShowDialogsHlpr
21:54:10 ShowDialogsGetDialog returned: nCurrent=0x2,index=1
21:54:10 Begin Action ShowDialogsHlpr: 0x2
21:54:10 Begin Action:  DialogShowSdMachineName
21:54:11 ShowDlgMachine returned: 1
21:54:11 Name = ZIZKA-59FF41BAF, Type = 0x1
21:54:11 Begin Action:  CheckRequirements
21:54:11 Processor Architecture: x86 (Pentium)
21:54:11 Service Pack:  768
21:54:11 ComputerName: ZIZKA-59FF41BAF
21:54:11 User Name: Nuclear
21:54:11 IsAllAccessAllowed returned: 1
21:54:11 OS Language: 0x405
21:54:11 End Action CheckRequirements
21:54:11 This combination of Package and Operating System allows a full product install.
21:54:11 CreateSetupTopology(ZIZKA-59FF41BAF), Handle : 0x14841d0, returned : 0
21:54:11 CreateSetupTopology returned : 0, Handle : 0x14841d0
21:54:11 Topology Type : 1, Return Value : 0
21:54:11 ST_GetPhysicalNode returned : 0, PNHandle : 0x1484220
21:54:11 PN_EnumerateEx returned : 0
21:54:11 PN_GetSQLStates returned : 0, SqlStates : 0x0
21:54:11 PN_StartScan [0x1484220] returned : 0
21:54:11 PN_GetNext [0x1484220] returned : 18, Handle: [0x0]
21:54:11 No more items in enumeration.
21:54:11 ReleaseSetupTopology
21:54:11 Named instance limit: 100, quota: 0
21:54:11 End Action  DialogShowSdMachineName
21:54:11 begin ShowDialogsUpdateMask
21:54:11 nFullMask = 0x8300037, nCurrent = 0x2, nDirection = 0
21:54:11 Updated Dialog Mask: 0xbf00037, Disable Back = 0x1
21:54:11 Dialog 0x2 returned: 0
21:54:11 End Action ShowDialogsHlpr
21:54:11 ShowDialogsGetDialog returned: nCurrent=0x4,index=2
21:54:11 Begin Action ShowDialogsHlpr: 0x4
21:54:11 Begin Action:  DialogShowSdInstallMode
21:54:12 ShowDlgInstallMode returned: 1
21:54:12 InstallMode : 0x1
21:54:12 End Action  DialogShowSdInstallMode
21:54:12 begin ShowDialogsUpdateMask
21:54:12 nFullMask = 0xbf00037, nCurrent = 0x4, nDirection = 1
21:54:12 Updated Dialog Mask: 0xbf40037, Disable Back = 0x1
21:54:12 Dialog 0x4 returned: 1
21:54:12 End Action ShowDialogsHlpr
21:54:12 ShowDialogsGetDialog returned: nCurrent=0x10,index=4
21:54:12 Begin Action ShowDialogsHlpr: 0x10
21:54:12 Begin Action:  DialogShowSdRegisterUserEx
21:54:12 End Action DialogShowSdRegisterUserEx
21:54:12 Dialog 0x10 returned: 1
21:54:12 End Action ShowDialogsHlpr
21:54:12 ShowDialogsGetDialog returned: nCurrent=0x20,index=5
21:54:12 Begin Action ShowDialogsHlpr: 0x20
21:54:12 Begin Action:  DialogShowSdLicense
21:54:13 End Action DialogShowSdLicense
21:54:13 Dialog 0x20 returned: 1
21:54:13 End Action ShowDialogsHlpr
21:54:13 ShowDialogsGetDialog returned: nCurrent=0x40000,index=18
21:54:13 Begin Action ShowDialogsHlpr: 0x40000
21:54:13 Begin Action:  DialogShowSdCliSvr
21:54:13 DisplaySystemPreReq
21:54:15 ShowDlgClientServerSelect returned: 1
21:54:15 Type : 0x2
21:54:15 End Action  DialogShowSdCliSvr
21:54:15 begin ShowDialogsUpdateMask
21:54:15 nFullMask = 0xbf40037, nCurrent = 0x40000, nDirection = 1
21:54:15 Updated Dialog Mask: 0xbfc0037, Disable Back = 0x1
21:54:15 Dialog 0x40000 returned: 1
21:54:15 End Action ShowDialogsHlpr
21:54:15 ShowDialogsGetDialog returned: nCurrent=0x80000,index=19
21:54:15 Begin Action ShowDialogsHlpr: 0x80000
21:54:15 Begin Action:  DialogShowSdInstanceName
21:54:15 Begin Action: ShowDlgInstanceName
21:54:17 End Action: ShowDlgInstanceName
21:54:17 ShowDlgInstanceName returned : 1
21:54:17 InstanceName : MSSQLSERVER
21:54:17 CreateSetupTopology(ZIZKA-59FF41BAF), Handle : 0x14841d0, returned : 0
21:54:17 CreateSetupTopology returned : 0, Handle : 0x14841d0
21:54:17 Topology Type : 1, Return Value : 0
21:54:17 ST_GetPhysicalNode returned : 0, PNHandle : 0x1484220
21:54:17 PN_EnumerateEx returned : 0
21:54:17 PN_GetSQLStates returned : 0, SqlStates : 0x0
21:54:17 PN_StartScan [0x1484220] returned : 0
21:54:17 PN_GetNext [0x1484220] returned : 18, Handle: [0x0]
21:54:17 No more items in enumeration.
21:54:17 ReleaseSetupTopology
21:54:17 End Action  DialogShowSdInstanceName
21:54:17 begin ShowDialogsUpdateMask
21:54:17 nFullMask = 0xbfc0037, nCurrent = 0x80000, nDirection = 1
21:54:17 Updated Dialog Mask: 0xbfc0037, Disable Back = 0x1
21:54:17 Dialog 0x80000 returned: 1
21:54:17 End Action ShowDialogsHlpr
21:54:17 ShowDialogsGetDialog returned: nCurrent=0x100000,index=20
21:54:17 Begin Action ShowDialogsHlpr: 0x100000
21:54:17 Begin Action:  DialogShowSdSetupType
21:54:17 Begin Action: Setup Type
21:54:19 SQL program folder: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
21:54:19 SQL data folder: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
21:54:19 Windows system folder: C:\WINDOWS\system32\
21:54:19 Prog req: 38073, Data req: 34432, Sys req: 158694
21:54:19 Prog avail: 967915440, Data avail: 967915440, Sys avail: 967915440
21:54:19 Prog req vs. avail, 231199, 967915440
21:54:19 Data req vs. avail, 34432, 967915440
21:54:19 Sys req vs. avail, 193126, 967915440
21:54:19 DisplaySystemPreReq
21:54:19 [SetupTypeSQL]
21:54:19 szDir = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
21:54:19 szDir = %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SQL Server
21:54:19 Result = 301
21:54:19 szDataDir = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
21:54:19 szDataDir = %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SQL Server
21:54:19 End Action: Setup Type
21:54:19 Setup Type: Typical (301)
21:54:19 End Action  DialogShowSdSetupType
21:54:19 begin ShowDialogsUpdateMask
21:54:19 nFullMask = 0xbfc0037, nCurrent = 0x100000, nDirection = 301
21:54:19 Updated Dialog Mask: 0xbdc0037, Disable Back = 0x1
21:54:19 Dialog 0x100000 returned: 301
21:54:19 End Action ShowDialogsHlpr
21:54:19 ShowDialogsGetDialog returned: nCurrent=0x400000,index=22
21:54:19 Begin Action ShowDialogsHlpr: 0x400000
21:54:19 Begin Action:  DlgServices
21:54:21 ShowDlgServices returned: 1
21:54:21 [DlgServices]
21:54:21 Local-Domain   = 3855
21:54:21 AutoStart      = 15
21:54:21 Result = 1
21:54:21 End Action DlgServices
21:54:21 begin ShowDialogsUpdateMask
21:54:21 nFullMask = 0xbdc0037, nCurrent = 0x400000, nDirection = 1
21:54:21 Updated Dialog Mask: 0xbdc0037, Disable Back = 0x1
21:54:21 Dialog 0x400000 returned: 1
21:54:21 End Action ShowDialogsHlpr
21:54:21 ShowDialogsGetDialog returned: nCurrent=0x800000,index=23
21:54:21 Begin Action ShowDialogsHlpr: 0x800000
21:54:21 Begin Action:  DlgSQLSecurity
21:54:22 ShowDlgSQLSecurity returned: 1
21:54:22 LoginMode = 1,szPwd
21:54:22 End Action DlgSQLSecurity
21:54:22 begin ShowDialogsUpdateMask
21:54:22 nFullMask = 0xbdc0037, nCurrent = 0x800000, nDirection = 1
21:54:22 Updated Dialog Mask: 0xbdc0037, Disable Back = 0x1
21:54:22 Dialog 0x800000 returned: 1
21:54:22 End Action ShowDialogsHlpr
21:54:22 ShowDialogsGetDialog returned: nCurrent=0x1000000,index=24
21:54:22 Begin Action ShowDialogsHlpr: 0x1000000
21:54:22 Begin Action:  DlgCollation
21:54:22 ShowDlgCollation returned: 1
21:54:22 collation_name = Czech_CI_AS,locale_name = Czech,lcid = 0x405,SortId = 0,dwCompFlags = 0x30001
21:54:22 End Action DlgCollation
21:54:22 begin ShowDialogsUpdateMask
21:54:22 nFullMask = 0xbdc0037, nCurrent = 0x1000000, nDirection = 1
21:54:22 Updated Dialog Mask: 0xbdc0037, Disable Back = 0x1
21:54:22 Dialog 0x1000000 returned: 1
21:54:22 End Action ShowDialogsHlpr
21:54:22 ShowDialogsGetDialog returned: nCurrent=0x2000000,index=25
21:54:22 Begin Action ShowDialogsHlpr: 0x2000000
21:54:22 Begin Action:  DlgNetwork
21:54:22 ShowDlgNetwork returned: 1
21:54:22 [DlgServerNetwork]
21:54:22 NetworkLibs = 255
21:54:22 TCPPort = 1433
21:54:22 TCPPrxy = Default
21:54:22 NMPPipeName = \\.\pipe\sql\query
21:54:22 Result = 1
21:54:22 End Action DlgNetwork
21:54:22 begin ShowDialogsUpdateMask
21:54:22 nFullMask = 0xbdc0037, nCurrent = 0x2000000, nDirection = 1
21:54:22 Updated Dialog Mask: 0xbdc0037, Disable Back = 0x1
21:54:22 Dialog 0x2000000 returned: 1
21:54:22 End Action ShowDialogsHlpr
21:54:22 ShowDialogsGetDialog returned: nCurrent=0x8000000,index=27
21:54:22 Begin Action ShowDialogsHlpr: 0x8000000
21:54:22 Begin Action:  DialogShowSdStartCopy
21:54:22 End Action DialogShowSdStartCopy
21:54:22 begin ShowDialogsUpdateMask
21:54:22 nFullMask = 0xbdc0037, nCurrent = 0x8000000, nDirection = 1
21:54:22 Updated Dialog Mask: 0xbdc0037, Disable Back = 0x1
21:54:22 Dialog 0x8000000 returned: 1
21:54:22 End Action ShowDialogsHlpr
21:54:22 ShowDialogsGetDialog returned: nCurrent=0x0,index=0
21:54:22 End Action ShowDialogs
21:54:22 Begin Action ProcessBeforeDataMove:
21:54:22 DeinstallStart returned (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL): 0
21:54:22 End Action   ProcessBeforeDataMove:
21:54:22 Begin Action SetToolsComponentSelection:
21:54:22 End Action SetToolsComponentSelection:
21:54:22 Begin Action ProcessComponentSelection:
21:54:22 End Action ProcessComponentSelection
21:54:22 Begin Action LogSelectedComponents:
21:54:22 SQLProg
21:54:22 SQLProg\SQLServr
21:54:22 SQLProg\SQLServr\Help
21:54:22 SQLProg\SQLServr\SCMDev
21:54:22 SQLProg\SQLServr\SCMDev\SCMh
21:54:22 SQLProg\SQLServr\SCMDev\SCMX86Lb
21:54:22 SQLProg\SQLServr\SCMDev\SCMALb
21:54:22 SQLProg\SQLServr\Rs1033
21:54:22 SQLProg\SQLServr\RsIntl
21:54:22 SQLProg\SQLServr\ActiveX
21:54:22 SQLProg\SQLServr\System
21:54:22 SQLProg\UpgTools
21:54:22 SQLProg\UpgTools\UpgSys
21:54:22 SQLProg\UpgTools\ActiveX
21:54:22 SQLProg\UpgTools\Res1033
21:54:22 SQLProg\UpgTools\ResOther
21:54:22 SQLProg\UpgTools\Resld
21:54:22 SQLProg\ReplSupp
21:54:22 SQLProg\ReplSupp\ReplDat
21:54:22 SQLProg\ReplSupp\RepComm
21:54:22 SQLProg\ReplSupp\RepNoDk
21:54:22 SQLProg\ReplSupp\ActiveX
21:54:22 SQLProg\Install
21:54:22 SQLProg\System
21:54:22 SQLProg\SvrExt
21:54:22 SQLProg\SvrExt\Help
21:54:22 SQLProg\SvrExt\SvrExtRs
21:54:22 SQLProg\SvrExt\ResIntl
21:54:22 SQLProg\Dat
21:54:22 SQLProg\DatSmpl
21:54:22 SQLProg\BaseSys
21:54:22 SQLProg\BaseBinn
21:54:22 SQLProg\BaseInst
21:54:22 SQLProg\Symbols
21:54:22 SQLProg\Symbols\EXE
21:54:22 SQLProg\Symbols\DLL
21:54:22 SQLProg\Perfmon
21:54:22 SQLProg\Perfmon\System
21:54:22 SQLProg\Root
21:54:22 MgtTool
21:54:22 MgtTool\SEM
21:54:22 MgtTool\SEM\HTML
21:54:22 MgtTool\SEM\MSD98
21:54:22 MgtTool\SEM\MSD98SYS
21:54:22 MgtTool\SEM\MSD98Res
21:54:22 MgtTool\SEM\MSD98Hlp
21:54:23 MgtTool\SEM\Help
21:54:23 MgtTool\SEM\Res1033
21:54:23 MgtTool\SEM\ResIntl
21:54:23 MgtTool\SEM\MSD98RsI
21:54:23 MgtTool\SEM\ActiveX
21:54:23 MgtTool\SEM\ActiveX\Res1033
21:54:23 MgtTool\SEM\ActiveX\ResIntl
21:54:23 MgtTool\SEM\Scripts
21:54:23 MgtTool\SEM\OLEDB
21:54:23 MgtTool\SEM\OLEDB\Res1033
21:54:23 MgtTool\SEM\OLEDB\ResIntl
21:54:23 MgtTool\Profiler
21:54:23 MgtTool\Profiler\Help
21:54:23 MgtTool\Profiler\Res1033
21:54:23 MgtTool\Profiler\ResIntl
21:54:23 MgtTool\Qryanlz
21:54:23 MgtTool\Qryanlz\Help
21:54:23 MgtTool\Qryanlz\Res1033
21:54:23 MgtTool\Qryanlz\ResIntl
21:54:23 MgtTool\DTCCLi
21:54:23 MgtTool\Wzcnflct
21:54:23 MgtTool\Wzcnflct\WzcnHlp
21:54:23 MgtTool\Wzcnflct\Wzcn1033
21:54:23 MgtTool\Wzcnflct\WzcnOthr
21:54:23 MgtTool\Wzcnflct\WzcnCmn
21:54:23 MgtTool\UtilSys
21:54:23 MgtTool\UtilBinn
21:54:23 Connect
21:54:23 Connect\ConnSys
21:54:23 Books
21:54:23 Books\Bookso
21:54:23 Books\Bookso\Utils
21:54:23 DevTools
21:54:23 DevTools\Dbg Int
21:54:23 DevTools\Dbg Int\Dbg Int Common
21:54:23 DevTools\Dbg Int\EXE
21:54:23 CoreRepl
21:54:23 CoreRepl\Res1033
21:54:23 CoreRepl\ResIntl
21:54:23 Core
21:54:23 Core\Res1033
21:54:23 Core\ResOther
21:54:23 Repostry
21:54:23 Repostry\RepstSys
21:54:23 Repostry\Res1033
21:54:23 Repostry\ResIntl
21:54:23 CoreMisc
21:54:23 CoreMisc\ActiveX
21:54:23 CoreMisc\ActiveX\Res1033
21:54:23 CoreMisc\ActiveX\ResIntl
21:54:23 CoreMisc\Res1033
21:54:23 Monarch
21:54:23 Monarch\Monr1033
21:54:23 Monarch\MonrIntl
21:54:23 Jet
21:54:23 CoreInst
21:54:23 CoreCOM
21:54:23 CoreCOM\Res1033
21:54:23 CoreCOM\ResIntl
21:54:23 CoreTool
21:54:23 CoreTool\Res1033
21:54:23 CoreTool\ResOther
21:54:23 DBLibCli
21:54:23 SFExt
21:54:23 SFExt\ActiveX
21:54:23 SFExt\ActiveX\Res1033
21:54:23 SFExt\ActiveX\ResIntl
21:54:23 SFExt\Res1033
21:54:23 SFExt\ResIntl
21:54:23 Trace
21:54:23 Trace\Res1033
21:54:23 Trace\ResOther
21:54:23 MiscCore
21:54:23 MC
21:54:23 MC\MC1033
21:54:23 MC\MCIntl
21:54:23 MC\Help
21:54:23 SQLMgr
21:54:23 SQLMgr\Res1033
21:54:23 SQLMgr\ResIntl
21:54:23 SvrTool
21:54:23 SvrTool\Res1033
21:54:23 SvrTool\ResIntl
21:54:23 DTSUI
21:54:23 DTSUI\Res1033
21:54:23 DTSUI\ResIntl
21:54:23 MSOlap
21:54:23 MSOlap\Res1033
21:54:23 MSOlap\ResIntl
21:54:23 ATL
21:54:23 ATL\winnt
21:54:23 ATL\win9x
21:54:23 MFC42U
21:54:23 VC
21:54:23 VB
21:54:23 OCX1
21:54:23 SQLAdHlp
21:54:23 SQLAdHlp\Res1033
21:54:23 SQLAdHlp\ResOther
21:54:23 {E07FDDBE-5A21-11d2-9DAD-00C04F79D434}
21:54:23 {E07FDDC7-5A21-11d2-9DAD-00C04F79D434}
21:54:23 {E07FDDC0-5A21-11d2-9DAD-00C04F79D434}
21:54:23 {E07FDDBF-5A21-11d2-9DAD-00C04F79D434}
21:54:23 End Action LogSelectedComponents
21:54:23 Begin Action InstallPkgs:
21:54:23 Begin Action: Locked Connectivity Files Check
21:54:23 ConnectivityLocked returned: 0
21:54:23 Operation has been suceffull ended. //Translated

21:54:23 End Action: Locked Connectivity Files Check
21:54:23 Setup is installing Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) ...
21:54:23 C:\SQLEVAL\x86\Other\sqlredis.exe /q:a /C:"setupre.exe WARN=1 -s -SMS"
21:54:30 ExitCode: 0
21:54:30 Setup is installing Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC) ...
21:54:30  C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\SqlSetup\Bin\cldtcstp.exe -SupportDir "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\SqlSetup\Bin" -DTCPkg "C:\SQLEVAL\x86\Other\dtcsetup.exe" -LogFile "C:\WINDOWS\sqlstp.log"
21:54:30 Process Exit Code: (0) 
21:54:30  /Q:A /T:C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\ixp001.tmp
21:54:30 Setup is installing HTML Help ...
21:54:30 HTML Help installer exit code: 0
21:54:51 End Action InstallPkgs
21:54:51 Begin Action MoveFileData:
21:54:51 Enabled SELFREGISTERBATCH
21:54:51 Enabled CORECOMPONENTHANDLING
21:55:01 Begin Action:  MoveFileDataSpecial
21:55:01 End Action:  MoveFileDataSpecial
21:55:01 End Action   MoveFileData
21:55:01 Begin Action ProcessAfterDataMove:
21:55:01 C:\SQLEVAL\x86\Binn\hhcol.exe C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Books
21:55:01 End Action   ProcessAfterDataMove
21:55:01 Begin Action BuildServer:
21:55:01 C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\SqlSetup\Bin\scm.exe  -Silent 1 -Action 5 -ExePath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\binn\sqlservr.exe" -Service "MSSQLSERVER"
21:55:02 Process Exit Code: (0) 
21:55:02 Begin Action: CreateRegistrySetSQL
21:55:02 End Action: CreateRegistrySetSQL
21:55:02 Begin Action: RegWriteSetupEntry
21:55:02 End Action: RegWriteSetupEntry
21:55:02 Begin Action: CreateSer
21:55:02 End Action: CreateSer
21:55:02 Begin Action: SkuIt
21:55:02 End Action: SkuIt
21:55:02 SetFileSecuritySQLAndAdmin for C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL returned: 0, 0
21:55:02 SetRegSecuritySQLAndAdmin for Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer returned: 0, 0
21:55:02 Begin Action: UpdateSystemPath
21:55:02 Path successfully updated.
21:55:02 %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\BINN
21:55:02 End Action: UpdateSystemPath
21:55:03 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\cnfgsvr.exe  -F "C:\WINDOWS\sqlstp.log" -I MSSQLSERVER -V 1 -M 0 -Q "Czech_CI_AS" -H 3211902 -U sa -P 
###############################################################################


Starting Service ...

Czech_CI_AS

-m -Q -T4022 -T3659

Connecting to Server ...

driver={sql server};server=ZIZKA-59FF41BAF;UID=sa;PWD=;database=master

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]SQL Server not exists or access denied. //Translated

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).

driver={sql server};server=ZIZKA-59FF41BAF;UID=sa;PWD=;database=master

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]SQL Server not exists or access denied. //Translated

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).

driver={sql server};server=ZIZKA-59FF41BAF;UID=sa;PWD=;database=master

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]SQL Server not exists or access denied. //Translated

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).

SQL Server configuration failed.

###############################################################################

21:57:03 Process Exit Code: (-1) 
22:56:35 Setup failed to configure the server.   Refer to the server error logs and C:\WINDOWS\sqlstp.log for more information.
22:56:35 Action CleanUpInstall:
22:56:35 C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\SqlSetup\Bin\scm.exe  -Silent 1 -Action 4 -Service SQLSERVERAGENT
22:56:35 Process Exit Code: (1060) Selected service not installed. // Translated

22:56:35 C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\SqlSetup\Bin\scm.exe  -Silent 1 -Action 4 -Service MSSQLSERVER
22:56:55 Action Exit Handler:
22:56:58 Process Exit Code: (0) 
22:56:58 StatsGenerate returned: 2
22:56:58 StatsGenerate (0x0,0x1,0xf000000,0x300,1033,303,0x0,0x1,0,0,0
22:56:58 StatsGenerate -1,Nuclear)
22:56:58 Installation Failed.
```

I've checked in the google stock in stage "installing service...." and I found if I have all NTFS permissions... Have administration permissions, but dont know NTFS permissions...

What's the problem?

Comment: Does the SQL Server service exist on the machine? As in does it show in the list of Services?

Comment: @SchmitzIT no, i nto find SQL server ... The installing is repeated, but fully removed from registers and others...  I dont know it is added SQL Server to services list .. I test it?

Comment: Did you check the log file mentioned at C:\WINDOWS\sqlstp.log? 

Also, out of curiosity, why would you want to install SQL 2k? In 2 months, that'll be completely unsupported.

Comment: @SchmitzIT C:\WINDOWS\sqlstp.log is here writed :) (In main post) i checked, but i dont know where is problem.... SQL 2k i install for game server... Can use SQL 2005, but must buying and main support ist SQL 2k...

Comment: Ah ok. I didn't get that bit that this was the log in question. I only see it fails to connect, but no other real errors in there that would give any good hints. 

Have you checked out SQL Server Express Edition? That's essentially free, though it comes with certain restrictions.

Comment: @SchmitzIT hmm, i test it.. But, i dont know the game supports the this SQL.. But thanx.. I really dont know why stock it... But i not running as Administrator, but sub account, but with admin access... Ok i test it...

Comment: Dont function :( I not have not updated the Windows, but writing the error not access to file and i must update the Windows.. I test it